# Can you extract line code line numbers from Android tombstone's backtrace?

Tags: android, crash-dumps

I'm trying to track down a crash in my android app, the backtrace looks like this:

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 000000000002233c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
    #01 pc 00000000000a48c8  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0x245c000)
    #02 pc 00000000000a4ac8  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0x245c000)
    #03 pc 00000000000b92b8  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0x245c000)
    #04 pc 00000000000b899c  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0x245c000)
    #05 pc 00000000000b891c  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0x245c000) (__cxa_throw+120)
    #06 pc 0000000000487638  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0xb2d000) (atlasCheckException(_JNIEnv*)+216)
    #07 pc 00000000004c717c  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0xb2d000) (_Z10callMethodIvJEEN14wrapped_resultIT_E4typeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectPKcDpOT0_+88)
    #08 pc 00000000004c70b4  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0xb2d000)
    #09 pc 0000000000914568  /data/app/com.mycompany.myapp-1KiUebYIp3DmANHiGZWOmQ==/base.apk (offset 0xb2d000)
    #10 pc 00000000000922c8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    #11 pc 0000000000023bf8  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+6
```

I read in google's documentation that why you see these base.apk (offset 0xXXXXXXXX) lines it means the symbols or line information has been stripped by the developer. I guess that's becaue this is a release build? I'm not sure. But is there anyway to look into these lines further? Like can I take that offset and find my way back to code somehow? I was trying to learn ndk-stack and addr2line but I wasn't having much luck with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Plz attach the whole tombstone log . only backtrace is not enough.

Comment: @cowboi-peng I tried to upload it but I broke the post character limit so here is a link https://pastebin.com/DZNzShp1

Comment: OK , I have a quick look at the log , seems it's a java exception  "Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::JavaException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 2, Size: 2'".